# Jest doesn't see the default export with ESM configured

Tags: jestjs, es6-modules, ts-jest

I'm using Jest with ts-jest module. I've followed the instructions on how to enalbe ESM, seems like ESM is working now. But when running tests, Jest doesn't see default export of my app, error:

`SyntaxError: The requested module '../app' does not provide an export named 'default'`

I've commented all tests, except the first one, now my test file looks like this:

```
describe("User registration", () => {
    it("GET should return 404", async () => {
        const res = await request(app).get("/api/register");
        assert.equal(res.statusCode, 404);
    });
}
```

app.ts:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import fileUpload from "express-fileupload";
import router from "./router/index";
import errorMiddleware from "./middlewares/error-middleware";
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
// enable req.ip
app.set("trust proxy", true);
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(express.json({ limit: "1000mb" }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
  })
);
app.use("/api", router);
app.use(errorMiddleware);

export default app;
```

The only thing i tried was replacing
`import app from "../app";` with `import { default as app } from "../app";`

Path to app.ts is correct

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "ES6" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,

    /* Modules */
    "module": "ES6" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "rootDir": "./src" /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */,
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */,
    "baseUrl": "./src" /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */,
    "sourceMap": true /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */,
    "outDir": "./build" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "noImplicitAny": true /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

Jest version: `^29.3.1`
TypeScript version: `4.9.4`

Comment: Need more imformation. Seems that you're using typescript. What is the jest and typescript version? You are using a tsconfig file? A file that can give all these clues would your package.json and the tsconfig file itself :)

Answer (score 1):

mate. Got rid of this error here. Looks like you just forgot to export the variable `app`... so, if everything is configured properly, adding this line to your `app.ts` should do the trick:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import fileUpload from "express-fileupload";
import router from "./router/index";
import errorMiddleware from "./middlewares/error-middleware";
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
// enable req.ip
app.set("trust proxy", true);
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(express.json({ limit: "1000mb" }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
    })
);
app.use("/api", router);
app.use(errorMiddleware);

export default app; // <--- THIS LINE HERE
```